# Как добавить картинку в WPF окно, если само приложение явлется консольным

Tags: c#, wpf, изображения

Вот к примеру, создала консольное приложение(.net) добавила WPF элемент, в который добавила

```
<Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="320,197,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Source="/Logo.png"/>
```

в конструкторе VisualStudio картинка есть, а при дебаге нету...
Смотрела как делают другие, они прописывают ассеты в App... Но у меня такого файла нету

Program:

```
namespace ConsoleApp8
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var windowThread = new Thread(qwer);
            windowThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            windowThread.Start();
            windowThread.Join();
            
        }
        public static void qwer()
        {
            new UserControl1().ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

Соседний файл UserControl1.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="ConsoleApp8.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ConsoleApp8"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="320,197,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Source="/Logo.png"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

UserControl1.xaml.cs:

```
namespace ConsoleApp8
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Логика взаимодействия для UserControl1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class UserControl1 : Window
    {
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: У консольного приложения есть окно консоли, там может быть только текст. Давайте подробнее, в текущем варианте вопрос непонятен. Покажите код приложения, как запускается это окно и где его XAML.

Comment: @aepot дополнила

Comment: Код-бихайнд окна не видно, покажите код класса `UserControl1`. А зачем вам консоль? Можно же нормальное WPF приложение создать.

Comment: @aepot UserControl1.xaml.cs вы про него?

Comment: Да, теперь вижу, выглядит нормально. Так зачем это все?

Comment: Я для простоты решила сделать в консольном для теста, изначально я делаю библиотку и проблема такая же =(

Comment: Проблема вот здесь `Source="/Logo.png"`, сборка не видит картинку. Контрол есть на самом деле, просто он прозрачный, в нем нет изображения. Нужно либо положить картинку так, чтобы сборка ее увидела, либо отредактировать путь к картинке так, чтобы сборка ее увидела.

Comment: Кстати, можете упростить старт, добавьте над `Main` аттрибут `[STAThread]`, а диалог вызывайте не из потока, а просто сразу `qwer();` в мейне. Не придется с потоками возиться, и код правильней будет выглядеть.

Comment: Вот в визуалке я вижу картинку, вроде как путь правильный, может нужно картинку как-то в проект подругому вставить? или варианты компиляции другие

Comment: [STAThread] а это удобно, спасибо)

Comment: Когда вы собрали проект, картинка в папке Debug есть? Вероятно нет. Скопируйте ее туда руками. Если она у вас в файлах проекта есть, то в обозревателе решения сделайте ей опцию копирования в выходную сборку, чтобы она автоматом при сборке копировалась.

Comment: Чтобы сделать Application, создайте новый WPF проект по шаблону и посмотрите, как App.cs и App.xaml.cs устроены, посмотрите код в Program.cs (до него может быть не легко добраться). Тогда поймете, как устроено WPF приложение и сможете повторить. Но проблема у вас не в этом, а именно в пути к картинке или отсутствии картинки. Попробуйте собрать картинку как Ресурс (Build Action = Resource) в обозревателе. А путь просто `Logo.png` без косой черты в начале.

Comment: В случе сборки картинки в ресурс, копирование в выходной каталог не требуется. Если будут глюки, нужно пересобрать (Rebuild) проект.

Comment: @aepot чуть позже попробую спасибо, отпишу о результате

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Указала файлу картинки "Действие при сборке": Resource

и указала нормальный путь `Source="assets\Logo.png"`

@aepot спасибо=)